# How to Login to website using macro and fetch whole data html table

Tags: vba, excel, session, excel-2007

i want to make a Macro fetcher which first login to the website then fetch html table data. i had fetched html table data from website which doesn't have login page but i got only first page data in excel sheet. i need to get all pages data of the table but first login to the webpage.
here is the code which get html table data from website.

```
Sub Macro1()
'
' Macro1 Macro
'
    With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
        "URL;https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/alt_pagination.html" _
        , Destination:=Range("$A$1"))
        .Name = "alt_pagination.html"
        .FieldNames = True
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .BackgroundQuery = True
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .WebSelectionType = xlSelectedTables
        .WebFormatting = xlWebFormattingNone
        .WebPreFormattedTextToColumns = True
        .WebConsecutiveDelimitersAsOne = True
        .WebSingleBlockTextImport = False
        .WebDisableDateRecognition = False
        .WebDisableRedirections = False
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With
    ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=-36
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I have done this separately.First macro will login into the website through IE and second will get the whole html table data.

```
     Sub Login()   
             Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.application")
            ie.Visible = True
           ie.Navigate ("https://www.facebook.com/?id=" & ActiveCell) 'Enter your website url
            Do
                If ie.ReadyState = 4 Then
                    ie.Visible = True
                    Exit Do
                Else
                    DoEvents
                End If
            Loop
            ie.document.forms(0).all("opername").Value = "myuser" 'Enter UserName
            ie.document.forms(0).all("password").Value = "mypass" 'Enter Password
            ie.document.forms(0).submit

               End With
        End Sub

Sub Macro1()
  With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
        "URL;https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/alt_pagination.html" _
        , Destination:=Range("$A$1"))
        .Name = "alt_pagination.html"
        .FieldNames = True
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .BackgroundQuery = True
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .WebSelectionType = xlSelectedTables
        .WebFormatting = xlWebFormattingNone
        .WebPreFormattedTextToColumns = True
        .WebConsecutiveDelimitersAsOne = True
        .WebSingleBlockTextImport = False
        .WebDisableDateRecognition = False
        .WebDisableRedirections = False
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With
End Sub
```